# How to set default numeric format to avoid showing exponential value?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, isql

I have a problem in [ASE isql](https://code.google.com/p/aseisql/) that it can't stop the execution when a negative exponential value is displayed.

```
select -1.2218952178955078e-006
```

Does anyone know how I can avoid exponential value by default?  Is there a setting available in session or I can do it by changing my locale?  Thanks.

Regards,
Jason

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'stop the execution" in first sentence ?

Exponential notation, is a way of your isql client. For example with float filed (rather real/ or double) it does not display exponential :

    create table mynumber (myfloat float)
    go
    
    insert into mynumber select (-1.2218952178955078e-006)
    go
    
    select * from mynumber
    go
    
    -0,000001

What is your current result for the `select -1.2218952178955078e-006` ?
What do you expect the displayed result to be ?